# How to set the credentials in a T-SQL script

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, credentials

I am trying to write a T-SQL script for insert.

I am running into trouble that it is using my windows credential and not the credential that I want for the script.

How can I set the credentials for the script if I want to???

Answer (score 0):

How are you running it?

If it's osql, you can do osql -U  -P

If its sqlcmd, you can do sqlcmd -U  -P

In both cases, -E instead will use integrated authentication (your username/password)

In management studio, just change how you connect to the server (in the connect menu).